# Transform duplicate values to 0 by keeping an element with conditionals

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr

Suppose there is a database in which:

```
x    y     z
a  2015  122.4
a  2015  122.4
b  2016  200.5
a  2014  300.6
c  2016  80.1
```

What I was wondering is to do in R a transformation that repeat values of z of each group x and y into 0, maintaining a value of z, with the final result being:

```
x    y     z
a  2015  122.4
a  2015    0
b  2016  200.5
a  2014  300.6
c  2016  80.1
```

I was thinking about dplyr, but I could not begin. How to do that?

Comment: Just use `duplicated` i.e. `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(x, y) %>% mutate(z = replace(z, duplicated(z), 0))`

Comment: That worked very well. Thnk you. But what if I want to do that with the same criteria but with multiple variables "z" at once?

Comment: In that case, use `mutate_at` or `mutate_all` i.e `df1 %>% group_by(x,y) %>% mutate_at(vars("z", "z1"), funs(replace(., duplicated(.), 0)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, after grouping by the selected column either apply on a single column with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(x, y) %>% 
   mutate(z = replace(z, duplicated(z), 0))
```

or for multiple columns `mutate_at` or `mutate_all` (depends on whether all the other columns are replaced or not)

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  mutate_at(vars("z", "z1"), funs(replace(., duplicated(.), 0)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   x, y [4]
#      x     y     z    z1
#  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     a  2015 122.4    42
#2     a  2015   0.0     0
#3     b  2016 200.5    39
#4     a  2014 300.6    41
#5     c  2016  80.1    21
```

NOTE: In this example, the `mutate_all` can also be used as all the columns are getting replaced

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., duplicated(.), 0)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c"), y = c(2015L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2014L, 2016L), z = c(122.4, 122.4, 200.5, 300.6, 80.1), 
z1 = c(42L, 42L, 39L, 41L, 21L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", 
 "z1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

`x[duplicated(x), "z"] <- 0`

You can do this in base R in one line. `duplicated` flags the duplicates without tagging the first entry.

Comment: Good answer. It might also be worth noting that if the OP has more than three columns in their data frame, they might want to specify the columns like this: df[duplicated(df[,1:3]), "z"] <- 0